Why my coding color is different from my console color while i use #fd0511 its convert into #b64d52 in console?
in this image i use #fd0511 but its not render 
I am trying to clone Netflix clone in react with tailwind css but my color is transform into different color
how to fix it? my actual color is cross in console.
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-row justify-between items-center px-[9.5rem] py-[1.2rem]">
        <div>
          <h1 className="text-[#fd0511] text-5xl font-semibold">NETFLIX</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="">
          <button className="text-[#FEF9FA] bg-[#E50914] text-[14px] text-center font-medium px-[1rem] py-[0.32rem] rounded-md z-10">
            Sign In
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </>
  );
}````


Because you have a second CSS clause for text-[#fd0511] that confusingly redefines the color as #b64d52.  It has to be in your stylesheet somewhere.

Your code should be fine.
From the screenshot you provided, it looks like it should be the darkreader browser extension that is modifying the styles. Try disabling that browser extension or browse in incognito mode and the issue should be resolved.
